# Power button (CSS change via button click )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on an HTML project.

Having issues with making a JavaScript that will work for what I'm looking for:

When a button is clicked, I want the `::before` css to change

and the `::after` css to change as well.

And when the button is clicked again, revert the css back to normal.

Basically making it seem as if a light on either side was glowing then the other glows when clicked.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Kib.png)

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($('.power::before').hasClass('on') == false) {
    $('.power::before').addClass('on');
    $(this).text('Small');
  } else {
    $('.power::before').removeClass('on');
    $(this).text('Big');
  }
});
```

```css
.power {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset -2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 2px #000 solid;
}

.power::before {
  content: " Standby ";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 38px;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background: #a52a2a;
  border: 1px #111 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-indent: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #000;
}

.power::after {
  content: " Power ";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 18px;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background: #7cfc00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #7cfc00, 0 0 5px #7cfc00;
  border: 1px #7cfc00 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-indent: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="power">
  <button>button click</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is stemming from a misunderstanding of what `::before` and `::after` are, which is css pseudo elements.

[Psuedo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) are basically what you'd think they are from the name, something that can be styled like a regular element, but it doesn't actually exist in the DOM. While `::before` and `::after` have the `content` property that may make them seem more like a regular DOM element, you need to remember that they are created and edited through CSS.

So, when you are trying to target the pseudo elements with jQuery, it's never going to return anything, because it has no access to the pseudo elements. 
`$('.power::before').hasClass('on')` is always going to return `false`.

What you need to do instead is toggle the class for `.power`, then style the pseudo elements when the class is present.

```js
var $pwr = $('.power');

$('button').on('click', function() {

  if (!$pwr.hasClass('on')) this.innerHTML = 'Turn Off';
  else this.innerHTML = 'Turn On';

  $pwr.toggleClass("on");
});
```

```css
.power {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset -2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 2px #000 solid;
}

.power::before {
  content: " Standby ";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 38px;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px #111 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-indent: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #000;
}

.power::after {
  content: " Power ";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  top: 18px;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px #111 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-indent: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #000;
}


/**
 If .on is set, add a background to the "Power" pseudo element
 */

.power.on:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #7cfc00, 0 0 5px #7cfc00;
  background: #7cfc00;
}


/**
 If .on is _not_ set, add a background to the "Standby" pseudo element
*/

.power:not(.on):before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #a52a2a, 0 0 5px #a52a2a;
  background: #a52a2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="power">
  <button>Turn On</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: by default it seems that off is on first

is it possible to make on first ?

Comment: @MitchellChelin It's quite easy to do so. Try looking over the last two rule sets in the CSS, then see if you can figure out what is going on and what you'd need to change to get the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code, I do not see any CSS rules for the 'on' class.

And when assigning the class, assign it to the target element, not the psuedo-class. `$('.power').addClass('on');`

```js
function test(el){
  el.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
#test::before,
#test::after{
  content: '';
  display: inline;
}
#test::before{ content: 'A '; }
#test::after{ content: ' B'; }
#test.change::before{ content: 'X '; }
#test.change::after{ content: ' Y'; }
```

```html
<button id="test" onclick="test(this)">TEST</button>
```

Another example, using your original code (but trimmed down the CSS a bit)

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  if( $('.power').hasClass('on') ){
    $('.power').removeClass('on');
    $(this).text('BIG');
  } else {
    $('.power').addClass('on');
    $(this).text('small');
  }
});
```

```css
.power {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px #000 solid;
}
.power::before {
  content: " Standby ";
  display: inline;
}
.power::after {
  content: " Power ";
  display: inline;
}
.power.on::before{
  content: " >>> ";
}
.power.on::after{
  content: " <<< ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="power">
  <button>button click</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add **html** to hold switch example:

```
<div id='controller_box'>CSS CHANGE ON CLICK<br><br><div id='light_holder'></div></div>
```

Hold **styles** in objects:

```
box_styles = {
"background" : "steelblue",
"border-radius" : "3px",
"color" : "white",
"height" : "100px",
"width" : "200px",
"padding" : "10px",
"font-family" : "arial"
}

btn_styles = {
"background" : "white",
"width" : "70px",
"display" : "inline-block",
"border" : "none",
"border-radius" : "2px",
"font-size" : "16px",
"cursor" : "pointer"
}

lighthold_styles = {
"background" : "white",
"color" : "white",
"height" : "30px",
"width" : "70px",
"float" : "right",
"padding" : "10px"
}

red_styles = {
"border-radius" : "50%",
"width" : "20px",
"background" : "darkred",
"color" : "red",
"float" : "right",
"margin-right" : "10px",
"margin-top" : "30px"
}

green_styles = {
"border-radius" : "50%",
"width" : "20px",
"background" : "limegreen",
"color" : "limegreen",
"float" : "right",
"margin-right" : "-20px",
"margin-top" : "-10px",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px limegreen",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px limegreen",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 30px 20px limegreen"
}

on_red = {
"background" : "red",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px red",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px red",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 30px 20px red"
}
off_red = {
"background" : "darkred",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0"
}

on_green = {
"background" : "limegreen",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px limegreen",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 10px 10px limegreen",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 30px 20px limegreen"
}

off_green = {
"background" : "green",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0",
"box-shadow" : "0 0 0 0"
}
```

**Add content and styling** as needed:

```
$('#controller_box').append("<button id='btn'>SMALL</button>").css(box_styles)
$('#btn').css(btn_styles)

$('#light_holder').append("<div id='red'>.</div><br><div id='green'>.</div>");

$('#red').css(red_styles)
$('#green').css(green_styles)
```

Handle **button click**:

```
btn_ct=0;
$('#btn').click(function() {
    btn_ct++;
    if((btn_ct % 2) == 0) { 
        $(this).text('SMALL')
        $('#green').css(on_green);
        $('#red').css(off_red);
    } else {
        $(this).text('BIG')
        $('#red').css(on_red);
        $('#green').css(off_green);
    }
    })
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a solution to the problem and a better one at that.

Comment: True, it is a solution to the problem in a way, but it's a terrible solution. To begin with, the question was about pseudo elements, which your answer completely disregarded. You are setting all of the styles, and creating non-dynamic elements with JS, which is just terrible practice(There's no reason to do this). You gave no explanation, and your code is simply a mess. Not trying to be discouraging, but this just isn't a good answer.

Comment: I doubt jQuery would allow setting styles with their library if it was considered such a bad practice. So, you're arguing against what is likely the most established javascript library on the planet. Also, my solution produces a result that doesn't look like it was made in 1995. Finally, it is unlikely the OP is invested in pseudo-elements..he is simply assuming this is what is needed to achieve the desired result.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery issue at all. Just because JS allows you to set styles doesn't mean you should set all of your styles with it. One or two, sure, that's fine. But CSS exists for a reason. It's far more efficient and cleaner to style with CSS then with JS. Just because you _can_ do it doesn't mean you _should_. Also, sure, your solution might look a bit better then the OP's styles, but the question isn't about how to style the elements to look best. In fact, a question like that doesn't fit on SO. If someone asks how to fix a bug, I'm not going to spend my answer critiquing their design.

Comment: Case in point, the `goto` statement which is available in several popular languages is often heavily discouraged as it usually always leads to bad code. Libraries/languages aren't perfect.

Comment: Many applications are now created dynamically, meaning content and styling get set on the fly. There is absolutely nothing wrong with storing style values in JS objects and adding them as needed. You're maintaining separate languages/files; I am maintaining one with no loss in separation of concern. And your "libraries aren't perfect" argument would go against CSS more than it would jQuery. CSS is hardly perfect. My approach is modern; yours is dated.

Comment: Yeah, no. You could potentially excuse storing styles in JS if you are using react or the like, but even [that has it's issues](https://medium.com/@gajus/stop-using-css-in-javascript-for-web-development-fa32fb873dcc). However you're using _jQuery_. Creating dynamic elements/styles in jQuery is simply a mess. jQuery is fairly slow, and used more on websites rather than webapps(where dynamic elements are generally used), saying it is the "modern" solution is simply incorrect. Your approach brings so many issues with it. Browser support, user with JS disabled, SEO, caching, performance.

Comment: There's just no reason to do it like this, and so many reasons not to. Sure, styles/elements stored in JS _do_ have their place, but it's a fairly specific place, and even then is up to the devs preference. We have no idea what the OP's situation is like, and a solution like this would just be a major pain for a new developer to learn from.